# CHECKBOX_GRID not converting in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX_GRID not converting in Google Forms.

Using Google Apps Script, I am trying to set the item, but I keep getting INVALID CONVERSION for CHECKBOX_GRID no matter what I have tried.  Other types convert fine.

Code Snippet below.

```
switch (items[i].getType()){
    case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX_GRID:
        //item = items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem();// INVALID CONVERSION
        //item = items[i].asGridItem();// INVALID CONVERSION
        //item = items[i].asCheckboxItem();// INVALID CONVERSION
        //item = items[i].asTextItem();// INVALID CONVERSION
        // TRIED THE CONVERSIONS ABOVE ALL FAIL WITH INVALID CONVERSION
    break
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found asCheckboxGridItem() worked, this is NOT documented in the google forms API. So hopefully this will be fixed by Google in the near future.

```
switch (items[i].getType()){
   case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX_GRID:
       item = items[i].asCheckboxGridItem();
    break
 }
```